# Is there a general name for this kind of filter?

Tags: filters, noise

I have a signal with some high frequency noise.

At first was just adding a low pass filter which removes the noise very well but has two drawbacks: First there is a delay (which I try to avoid in my application) and second, if the input signal changes suddenly (from 10% to e.g. 50% of the maximum input level), the filter removes the high frequency part too and the transition is smoothed out and/or overshoots. This is both expected.

A second idea I implemented is just a kind of bit reduction (in my case a fraction of a few bits). It seems that currently this is exactly what I need. Noise is perfectly removed, there is zero delay, and high frequencies are still preserved.

My only question is, is there a name for this kind of filter (to investigate some further ideas)?

Comment: The noise is not removed if you requantise, it's only covered by the quantisation error. This is not a good idea.

Comment: Not a filter, but the non-linear function of zeroing a signal below a certain threshold (possibly some number of LSBs) is called a noise gate.

Comment: @hotpaw, noise gate seems to remove noise only if the signal is below a certain threshold, while this is not true in my case. Is there a reason why you would call a noise gate not a filter? filters can IMHO be non linear too.

Comment: @jazzmaniac, you maybe have a better idea than? What is if if you have a 10 bit image/video and you remove the 2 lowest bits e.g. and you end up a with a 8 bit image/video which has case noticeable less noise.